# R: Interpolation with estimation of SE given non-linear data with mean and SE at each x value

Tags: r, interpolation, standard-error

I have non-linear data of the form:

```
Time    logEC50 SE
24.98368611 -1.587216   0.246261
48.387575   0.984998    0.107624
72.01801111 1.801870    0.067705
95.84422778 2.3387867   0.0660584
167.5951389 3.1726153   0.0655344
```

I would like to predict the logEC50 value at time *t* within the range of the data, and also predict the SE at *t* that incorporates the SE information provided in the data.

Comment: Predict via what? You could model the results of the model these are based upon, but it'd be much more accurate to just use that model directly.

Comment: My original model doesn't include the time component, but I think I understand what you mean.  These are summarized dose-response curve data of the same samples observed at different time points (calculated from the drc package).  72 h is the canonical time I wish to report the EC50 at, but for some datasets (unlike this data set), 72 h is in-between measurements.  Have to figure out how to include time in the model.

Comment: Exactly. If time is in your model, it's just a matter of calling `predict` (or the equivalent).